# Why Won't This Work? - It won't show users email address

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Why won't the last line of the above code show the email for the current user? Have being trying to do this for days, I think I have requested the right permission's?

Any help is appreciated, might even share a few pound / dollars on PayPal to the person who can help me get out of this mess!

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require 'src/facebook.php';
$app_id = "211665122244023";


     $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/midcitymafia/";

     $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$user_id = $data["user_id"];
     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
                         $graph1 = file_get_contents ("https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id . "/?accesstoken=" . $data["oauth_token"]);
         $graph=json_decode($graph1,true);
     }



$userid =  $user_id;
$username = $graph['name'];
$usergender = $graph['gender'];
$useremail = $graph['email'];

?>

<br>

<?php echo 'ID: ' . $userid; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Name: ' . $username; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Gender: ' . $usergender; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Email: ' . $useremail; ?>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I didn't think that facebook gave out email addresses through the API.

Comment: I'm sure it does you just have to request extended permissions, which I have... You may be right?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($graph)` so you can see what all you're getting back.

Comment: array(7) { ["id"]=> string(10) "1469088864" ["name"]=> string(10) "Jack Brown" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "Jack" ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Brown" ["username"]=> string(11) "thebestjack" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_GB" }

Comment: Upon investigation - they sure do: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ Seems odd as I would have thought they would want people to visit their service rather than be emailed directly by app developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need extended permissions for email. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

You can pass req_perms=email  in the API call

Comment: Isn't this what I have done here?...  $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";

Comment: ah thats true, didn't see that.. Did you check that the your test user has given the email permissions ?

Comment: When I go to my authorised apps on my Facebook account settings under this app it says "this apps needs your email address "blahblah@yahoo.co.uk"...

Comment: hmm.. its sure is strange, I can suggest you to use the SDK instead of file_get_contents()

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ . it uses cURL POST method instead of GET to fetch data. It shouldn't be different results ,but its Facebook. The API is created and maintained by bunch of idiots who change things every second

Comment: But it seems its just not getting the correct page for the graph URL... maybe I'm implementing the access token wrong?